# Learning roadmap for additive combinatorics

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, additive-combinatorics

I have read Calculus by Michael Spivak. Now I want to learn additive combinatorics though I have no experience with combinatorics or probability theory. To my understanding, there is a book on the subject by Terence Tao and Vu. Do you think I'll be able to read it thoroughly? Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: No, the book by Tao and Vu will not be accessible for you yet, unfortunately. It is beautiful material, though, and some parts are accessible with your background. For some details, and more suggestions, see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/a/46790/6085), and the other answers in that thread.

Comment: (Not knowing basic combinatorics may actually be the real obstacle for you. I would suggest you start there.)

Comment: So this is the list of books to read I've made for myself:1)Enumerative combinatorics.2)Combinatorial Number Theory and Additive Group Theory.3)The Classical Bases.4)Inverse Problems and the Geometry of Sumsets.5)Elementary Methods in Number Theory.6)Sequences, by Halberstam and Roth.7)The Probabilistic Method, by Alon and Spencer.8)Ramsey Theory, by Graham, Rothschild, and Spencer.Is this list sufficient?

Comment: Hopefully not. :-) It is a beautiful area. The list is certainly a good start.